# Apache Rewrite get source URL via PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using the Facebook Open Graph Protocol in a single page AngularJS site.

To allow for dynamic OG content I am redirecting the crawlers to a static HTML page containing the populated OG meta tags.

The static page is created with some PHP:

```
<?php

makePage();

function makePage() {
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta property="og:title" content="Dynamic" />
            <meta property="og:description" content="Dynamic" />
            <meta property="og:url" content="Dynamic" />
            <meta property="og:image" content="Dynamic" />
            <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        </head>
    </html>
    <?php
}
?>
```

And to redirect on the Apache server I have the following in the htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-  9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mydomain/static-page.php [P]
```

Note the P flag which has Apache perform a remap.

More details on my approach can be found here:

http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app

**My question:** within the PHP how do I gather the originating URL?

I would like to use this URL to determine the content for each of the og meta properties.

If I use:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

I get the URL of the static file, i.e. /static-page.php

But I would like the URL prior to the redirect/remap.

Many Thanks
Hanks